# How to store multiple relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store more than one relationship using the whereHas but i am unable to solve my issue using this.

```
$email = $request->input('email');
$first_name = $request->input('first_name');

User::whereHas('userBasicInfo',function( $query ){
        $query->where('email', $email);
})->whereHas('userContactInfo', function ( $query ) {
        $query->where('first_name', $first_name);
```

How i can get my records using two parameters that is `email` and `first_name` but it displaying

> un-defined $email and $first_name

which i have declared in my `where` cluase.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variable(s) to closure function using `use` keyword;

```
User::whereHas('userBasicInfo',function( $query ) use ($email){
    $query->where('email', $email);
})->whereHas('userContactInfo', function ( $query ) use ($first_name){
    $query->where('first_name', $first_name);

// For multiple variables pass.
User::whereHas('userBasicInfo',function( $query ) use ($email, $first_name){
    $query->where('email', $email);
    $query->where('first_name', $first_name);
});
```